# vnc grey screen (16.04, tightvnc, gcp, ) :

Tags: lubuntu, vnc, google

I was able to see the destkop when I was using `"sudo reboot"` on the GCP instance but when I `stopped` and `started` the GCP instance , I get a grey screen now.

I used these steps to set up the desktop on the GCP instance the first time.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
$ sudo apt-get install autocutsel
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-core
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-themes-standard
```

and this is what my ~/.vnc/xstartup

```
#!/bin/sh
autocutsel -fork
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="GNOME-Flashback:Unity"
export XDG_MENU_PREFIX="gnome-flashback-"
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
gnome-session --session=gnome-flashback-metacity --disable-acceleration-check --debug &
```

How can I deal with this gray screen after "Stopping a